# Why isn't this mob farm working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've played minecraft for a long time, and I've used this farm everytime without any problems, but now its not working. Here are some pictures of it:

[image]
[image]
Pretty far away from land.....
[image]

I'm standing 76 blocks away if my math is right. When they spawn they should drop down.

Comment: @Murydary could you add details to make it clear what the problem is?

Comment: Problem is the mobs isnt spawning, i think i have it good, but mobs will dont spawn in there....

Comment: How many blocks below where the mob farm is are you waiting?

Comment: Wait ill check ;)

Comment: 74 - 150 so 76 blocks if my math is right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you within the mob spawning radius? You must be within 24 blocks of the tile that you want mobs to spawn for them to appear. This is **VERY** important.

Comment: Ahhh thats it ! Thx <3

Answer (score -1):

Turn the difficulty from easy to hard, not peaceful.

Comment: I have it on hard......